# Case-insenstive ordered word search via regular expression

Tags: regex, string, perl, search

I just started off with regular expression in perl. After playing around through various online tutorials, I wanted a write a regular expression that matches order specified case insensitive word match.

I'm trying to determine if string "A" consists of a word or a sequence of words of string "B", and I want to do this case-insensitively.

For example, if string "B" is "John Von Neumann", then "JOhn", "Von NeumaNn", "VoN", "john neuMann" would be a **match**, but strings like "Joh", "NeumaNn VoN", "Vonn" would **not** be a match.

I am not sure how to do this with regular expressions, any idea?

Comment: @ogzd posted `/^(?=.)(?:\bjohn\b)?\s*(?:\bvon\b)?\s*(?:\bneumann\b)?\z/i` (with some help). I'm not sure why he deleted it. It's not a general purpose-solution, but the OP might not need a general purpose solution.

Comment: @ikegami: `(?=.)` needs to be `(?=\S)` otherwise the pattern will match a string of whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

Let's ignore case for a second.

```
John Von Neumann
```

can be matched by

```
John Von Neumann    1 1 1
John Von            1 1 0
John     Neumann    1 0 1
John                1 0 0
     Von Neumann    0 1 1
     Von            0 1 0
         Neumann    0 0 1
```

So the regex pattern for which you are looking is

```
/^(?:John Von Neumann|John Von|John Newmann|John|...)\z/i
```

Here's how you can build the list:

```
sub true_indexes {
   my ($n) = @_;
   my $i = 0;
   my @indexes;
   while ($n) {
      push @indexes, $i if $n & 1;
      ++$i;
      $n >>= 1;
   }
   return @indexes;
}

my @words = split(' ', 'John Von Neumann');

my @patterns;
unshift @patterns, join ' ', @words[ true_indexes($_) ]
   for 1 .. (2**@words)-1;
```

And finally, we can generate the pattern:

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @patterns;
my $re = qr/$pat/i;
```

You'd use it like such:

```
if ($input =~ /^$re\z/) {
   print "match\n";
} else {
   print "no match\n";
}
```

Comment: @kamata nice usage of Perl syntax

Comment: I think ogzd's solution is much better than this solution, if used as base to build the generalized regex. This solution will build a humongous regex for longer phrase (the DFA can be reduced, but the fact that the regex is humongous won't change). Not sure why this gets so many upvotes.

Comment: @nhahtdh, ogzd's solution cannot be used to build a generalised regex. It can only be used anchored by `^`..`\z` and `^`..`$` because it can match nothing. Also, you're wrong about the size. The regex engine will create a trie for the alternation, which will cut the time and memory needed to "nothing". Finally, mine is much faster because his can do an insane amount of backtracking.

Comment: @ikegami: The regex engine is one thing (the implementation is likely to implement something efficient for simple cases like this), but the string before feeding to the regex engine is potentially very big. And since the words are ordered, it is possible to just use optional operator to match them.

Comment: @nhahtdh, The more words, the better my solution. ogzd could backtrack til the heat death of the universe, I think. (It would be possible to avoid this by preprocessing `$input` and making a change to the pattern.)

Comment: @nhahtdh, His pattern is basically of the form `.*.*.*.*.*.*`.

Comment: No, `\s*` is not different from `.*` to determine whether this problem can occur, and 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 is still a huge factor (>1000x) for 10 words.

Comment: @ikegami: Instead of arguing, to be more constructive, how about writing a test?

Comment: @nhahtdh, Honestly, this is already way too much spam about someone else's solution in comments to mine. But sure, feel free to write the test and post your own answer.

Comment: @ikegami: You are right about ogzd answer being subject to backtracking hell. However, my point still holds about the size of the string. I have written an answer to address that problem.

Answer (score 3):

ikegami's solution will take up exponential space for to store the string before it is turned into regex (each word will appear 2<sup>n - 1</sup> times, where n is the number of words, so the total space is at least 2<sup>n - 1</sup> * Sum(length of words)). This is **not** related to the regex engine - since the problem is before the string is turned into regex.

---

A regex construction equivalent (in term of the set of strings that it matches) to ikegami's solution would be:

```
^(?=[^ ])(?:(?: |^)John(?= |\z))?+(?:(?: |^)Von(?= |\z))?+(?:(?: |^)Neumann(?= |\z))?+\z
```

This only takes up linear space, in term of the number of words and the total length of all the words.

For clarity:

```
^
(?=[^ ])
(?:(?: |^)John(?= |\z))?+
(?:(?: |^)Von(?= |\z))?+
(?:(?: |^)Neumann(?= |\z))?+
\z
```

The look-ahead assertion `(?=[^ ])` has 2 purposes: prevent the empty string from being matched, and make sure the first character is not a space character.

Note the `?+`, which makes the quantifier *possessive* (or *atomic*), since we don't need backtracking here. ***Why?*** If we were to do this normally, we will loop through the list of words and compare it with the left most word in the input. After we find a match, we will continue the loop to compare it with the next word in the input, until all words in the input has been found or we have finished looping the list of words.

The *possessive* quantifier also prevent backtracking hell from happening. If a word is considered a match, it will never be reconsidered again.

For each word, they can be preceded by a space, or it is the start of the string. The look-ahead assertion `(?= |\z)` has the purpose of making sure words with same prefix doesn't get matched incorrectly at first try (e.g. `"John Von Vone"`, try to match `"John Vone"`).

Since there is no backtracking, the worst case performance is linear in term of length of all the words and the length of the input string (the same as how you would do it without regex).

---

We can change the regex a little bit to allow flexible spacing:

```
^(?= *+[^ ])(?: *+John(?= |\z))?+(?: *+Von(?= |\z))?+(?: *+Neumann(?= |\z))?+ *+\z
```

For clarity (leading space is significant):

```
^
(?= *+[^ ])
(?: *+John(?= |\z))?+
(?: *+Von(?= |\z))?+
(?: *+Neumann(?= |\z))?+
 *+
\z
```

The look-ahead `(?= *+[^ ])` at the beginning makes sure the input string does not contain only spaces.

The regex is changed to allow any amount of spaces precede a word (backtracking disallowed by possessive quantifier). 0 or more quantifier `*` is used, for the case the word is right at the beginning of the string. There is no chance for 2 words to collide, due to the look-ahead assertion `(?= |\z)`.

It still takes up linear space when constructing the string (before entering it to the regex engine). Worst case performance is also linear.

---

**Extreme cases**

1. The original words:

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1 ... aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa9 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ... aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA ... aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaZ
   ```

   (Each word is 20 characters, the last character changes from `0-9`, then `a-z`, then `A-Z`)

   Strings to search for (not matching):

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay
   ```

   (`y` can only come before `z`)
2. The original word:

   ```
   patterns used in Perl pattern matching evolved from those supplied
   ```

   (Some normal words)

   Strings to search for (not matching):

   ```
   patterns used in Perl pattern matching evolved from those suppliedd
   ```

   (Extra `d` at the end)
3. The original word:

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaa
   ```

   (Word contains only `a`, with different length.)

   Strings to search for (not matching):

   ```
   aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
   ```

   (Extra `a` at the end)
4. The original word:

   ```
   performance abc xyz performance 456 !@# performance
   ```

   (Same word appearing multiple times)

   Strings to search for (not matching):

   ```
   performance performance performance performance
   ```