# Is that "StackOverflowError" on Java RegularExpressions always means necessity to optimise Regex?

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

To read CSV files, I have the following regular expression in Java:

```
Pattern csvline = Pattern.compile("((([^\\\"]|\\\"\\\")+|\\\"([^\\\"]|\\\"\\\")+\\\"))*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This expression passes [this online Regex test](http://regexpal.com/). However, when running it it always throws a `StackOverflowError`.

After some research, I found the solution is to replace the expression by

```
Pattern csvline = Pattern.compile("((([^\\\"]|\\\"\\\")++|\\\"([^\\\"]|\\\"\\\")++\\\"))*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Here I use possessive quantifiers instead of greedy ones. In this case, it also though to be an optimization.

My question is, is that because Java cannot process to many backtracking (it consumes stack space, which I believe a good engine should'nt the case), so any time when your see the `StackOverflowError` caused by regular expressions, you should think about optimize in a way to reduce backtracking?

Comment: Just curious... does that regex supports something like `word1,word2,"word3,and,word4"`?

Comment: Why do you need additional parenthesis around? The same regexp: `(([^\\\"]|\\\"\\\")+|\\\"([^\\\"]|\\\"\\\")+\\\")*`

Comment: @OscarMederos Yes this is just part of the story. This expression is just to determine weather the current line is part of a "real" line. In case that a quoted field contains a line break, the "current" line will need to combine with the following line(s). So the algorithm is to rebuild the whole lines before additional processing.

Comment: @pstr You are perfectly right. That could be a result of previous tuning of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Java throwing `StackOverflowError` shows that the matching is done internally by recursive call. This is bad, but also good in its own way, since it indicates potential problem with your regex.

The backtracking hell is induced by the fact that you do finitely many matching `+` inside another finitely many matching `*`: `((A+|B))*` (this is the *form* of your regex).

Usually, if you can write a non-regex solution that doesn't need to backtrack and doesn't require a stack (like bracket matching problem), then you can write a regex with possessive quantifier (adding extra `+` after the normal quantifiers) that performs the same task, since possessive quantifier doesn't (allow) backtrack, which is similar to what you do in non-regex solution.

Comment: This is a sample to the claim I made above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14811222/1400768 . The question was about checking whether a sentence is a subsequence of a full sentence, at the granularity of a word (order of the words must follow, but the words does not need to make up a contiguous part of the full sentence).

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Java regex engine is broken. It uses backtracking so it can support back-references, and as a result has the same pathological exponential space/time problems common to all perl-like regex-engines. You are right, that it could potentially analyse the expression to determine it is in fact regular, and use the polynomial-space/time algorithm you expected.

In cases like this I always recommend either using cascading regexes, preferably via [JFlex](http://jflex.de/), although doing them by hand is not too painful provided you stick to 2 or 3 levels. More than that it will be much more maintainable and easier to write and debug if you use a lexer.

The idea is that you parse the line by repeated application of simple regexes. In your case, the first identifies the start of the next field; the second identifies the end of the field (capturing the contents); the third checks for a 'next field'; repeat.

These are almost identical to the 3 tokens you would recognise using JFlex the only difference being an field-separator token which is so simple you would probably include it in the 'end-of-field' regex when doing it manually.